# Убрать промежутки между данными при отображении на графике

Tags: c#, winforms, диаграммы

Есть графический объект `Chart`. В нем выставил значения по X с типом `DateTime`. У меня массив дат имеет небольшие промежутки, некоторые дни могут быть пропущены и поэтому на графике появляются соответствующие пропуски, как можно график сомкнуть, чтобы пропусков не было видно?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Заполните промежутки предыдущим известным значением.

Comment: @free_ze там везде разные пропуски дат могут быть, это всё слишком долго.

Comment: А также можно выставить 0 вместо null значения у пропущенных дней. Я так полагаю, что выставив 0 в дни пропуска, на плоскости x,y это будет как линия, паралельная оси x. Хотя с вашим графиком, совет от free_ze более полезен т.к. действительно уберет пропуски (но тогда данный график нельзя будет считать достоверно точным).

Comment: @alexoander В итоге я вместо Х поставил значения индекса счетчика `i` и тогда он сплошной, но теперь вопрос, как выставить например значение дат на оси Х только в начале месяца, чтобы знать, где значения по месяцам расположены

Comment: @Fresto, у меня такое подозрение, что контрол можно настроить на отображение непрерывных графиков. _Вы решили не рассказывать, на чем делаете интерфейс, поэтому пока ничем помочь не могу._

Comment: VS C# Winforms - `Chart`

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd456698.aspx это?